# Component rendering on same page instead of a new page in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React JS, just spent a few days with it actually. I'm currently trying to handle navigation between different pages.

Basically, what I currently want to do is that when I click 'Sign in' on the SigninForm screen, I want it to navigate to a new 'SupervisorDashboard' page, which currently has dummy h1 text saying "This is a test".

Currently, when I click on the Sign in button, "This is a test" renders below the button instead of rendering on a new page. The url updates but the h1 text displays on the same page instead of a new one.

I have tried tons of solutions on StackOverflow as well as other websites, but none seem to be working, which makes me think that I'm making a trivial mistake. Can anyone have a look at my **SignInForm.js** code and figure out what's the problem?:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import SupervisorDashboard from '../pages/SupervisorDashboard';


class SignInForm extends Component {



render() {

    return (

      <Router>

        <div className="FormCenter">

        <form className="FormFields" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

          <div className="FormField">

            <label className="FormField__Label" htmlFor="cnic">CNIC</label>

            <input type="text" id="cnic" className="FormField__Input" placeholder="Enter your CNIC without dashes" name="cnic"/>

          </div>

          <div className="FormField">

          <Link to={{
              pathname: '/SupervisorDashboard'
            }} className="FormField__Button mr-20">Sign In</Link>

            </div>


        </form>

        <Route exact path="/SupervisorDashboard" component={SupervisorDashboard}>

        </Route>


      </div>


      </Router>
    );
}
}

export default SignInForm;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basicly a `Route` element always gets rendered, when the `path` prop is fitting.

So you render your `SupervisorDashboard` whenever the url is "/SupervisorDashboard". By using a switch and multiple `Render` elements you *switch* between all render elements based on your url

I corrected your code. This is pseudocode, I can not test this code at this very moment, but you should see what I have changed:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import SupervisorDashboard from '../pages/SupervisorDashboard';

class SignInForm extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact render={() => {
                    return (
                        <div className="FormCenter">
                            <form className="FormFields" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                <div className="FormField">
                                    <label className="FormField__Label" htmlFor="cnic">CNIC</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="cnic" className="FormField__Input" placeholder="Enter your CNIC without dashes" name="cnic"/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="FormField">
                                    <Link to={{
                                        pathname: '/SupervisorDashboard'
                                    }} className="FormField__Button mr-20">Sign In</Link>

                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    );
                }}/>
                <Route exact path="/SupervisorDashboard" component={SupervisorDashboard} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default SignInForm;
```

Comment: Your code is working fine (except for a missing import for Switch), and your explanation was extremely helpful for someone new to React JS, marked your answer as correct.